# What are the characteristics of a good chess board?

Tags: chessboards, chess-set

I just read the question: [What are some good quality magnetic chess sets?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/what-are-some-good-quality-magnetic-chess-sets) and I was left with a few more general questions:

1. What is a comfortable board size for home vs travel?
2. What height of chess pieces are most common?
3. What type of wood indicates a quality board?
4. What board companies are most reputable?
5. Are magnetic boards good to have for home tables?
6. Any other important things to consider when purchasing a board?

Comment: I think this could safely be made into four or five separate questions, if you want detailed answers!

Comment: Yeah for sure! In that case I'll make some additional questions today.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I just created a new qusetion related to board companies: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/what-chess-board-companies-are-the-most-reputable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. home - 3.75" king on 2.25" squares. Travel - no opinion. But the USCF used to sell a chess board 'wallet' that would fold up (with the pieces) and go in your pocket. Perhaps they still do.
2. 3.75" King for me. No more, no less.
3. Any hardwood.  I like maple and walnut.
4. [House of Staunton](http://www.houseofstaunton.com/), but you'll pay top dollar. While you are there, check out their [Reykjavic II chess set](http://www.houseofstaunton.com/the-reykjavik-ii-series-chess-set-3-75-king.html).  Ah, the [board and set combo (with a box!) is on sale](http://www.houseofstaunton.com/the-reykjavik-ii-series-chess-set-and-board-combination.html). I prefer boxwood and ebony, but boxwood and ebonized boxwood works for me too.
5. It is unnecessary.
6. A vinyl board just rolls up - easy to store, easy to take to the club. Another option is to make your own. Here's [one I made](http://tony-stormcrow.blogspot.com/2009/10/i-finished-another-chessboard.html).  [And here's another](http://tony-stormcrow.blogspot.com/2008/05/making-chessboard.html), with the steps I took.

Comment: As of June 13, 2018, USCF still has a "checkbook" board with magnetic pieces: https://www.uscfsales.com/checkbook-magnetic-travel-chess-set.html