# What chessboard companies are the most reputable?

Tags: chessboards, recommendations

As a follow up to my original question [What are the characteristics of a good chess board?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6420/what-are-the-characteristics-of-a-good-chess-board) I was wondering what companies are the most reputable for chessboard construction. Since I am just a beginner I am curious at lower cost beginner boards, but also in other boards that I might want to splurge on one day if I really get into chess.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a request for shopping recommendations.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The emphasis is on companies, not products

Comment: I'm not sure that's a massive distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard vinyl board is hard to beat for everything except showing off a chess set.  You can get them for cheap from the USCF or from any other purveyor of chess gear.

Here's one from [Cajun chess for $4](http://www.king-cart.com/cgi-bin/cart.cgi?store=CajunChess&category=Vinyl%20and%20Rollup%20Chess%20Boards).  I bought a few sets from them. I like them.

Looks like tournament-sized wooden boards begin at $50.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know any cheap chess board companies, but checking out websites like
[The Chess House](http://www.chesshouse.com/chess_board_s/151.htm) can yield very good results.

For a nice splurge, the best boards are without a doubt the [DGT](http://www.digitalgametechnology.com/site/products/electronic-boards) ones,

Answer (score 2):

Most reputed brand in Chess boards is probably Staunton. They are manufactured by 
Jacques of London and have been in circulation since 1849!

Answer (score 1):

DGT chessboards are the best. The digital chessboards are definitely helpful in your chess career, besides, the quality is really good; the only downside is that it is quite expensive. However, I would say the board is worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

The most reputable chessboard company I know is chessbazaar.com. They are the finest crafters of chess pieces and boards and they do it at the lowest price in the industry. the quality is not compromised.

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Are you affiliated with this company? If so, you need to [explicitly state so](/help/promotion).

Comment: no! I just bought some products from them which I felt are good for users to try.

Answer (score 1):

UK and Europe based can order chess board from [Discover Handicrafts](https://discoverhandicrafts.com/collections/games-and-puzzles/products/folding-chess-board-set-wooden-game-handmade-classic-game-of-brilliance-small-chess-pieces-10-inches-non-magnetic-4237766)

Their chess boards are made from wood and very artistics.

Answer (score 0):

### "Caveat Emptor"

A lot of the chess sets out there *look* pretty nice, but frankly most of the manufacturers invest all their effort into attractive molds and durable plastic.  Very few of them offer even the most basic features that you would expect in this day and age - the features that would most enhance your game.

I just spent over $50 for a tournament set for my son.  Yes, it has hefty, triple-weighted pieces for stability and an attractive Staunton design, and the pieces seem very durable.  The set even came with extra queens - a nice touch for those four-queen positions you get every once in a while.  But look at what it doesn't have:

- Undo.  This feature has been in cheap word processors since the '80's, but is totally missing from the set.
- Syntax Checking.  The set allows illegal moves without so much as a warning. This has been a feature of programming editors since the '90s.
- Speed Regulation.  The set allows me to make moves as hastily as I want, even though my game always suffers as a result.  For goodness sake, the *escapement* has been a part of clocks since the *13th Century*!
- Drink Holders.  Ok, this one is just a personal preference, but my minivan comes with about 16.  You would think that a chess set would have space for at least two.

The upshot:  It doesn't seem to matter how much you spend, you aren't going to get these sorts of features.  So if you ask me, *all* the companies out there are ripping us off.  The USCF has been doing it the longest - I suppose there is some merit to the thought that if you are going to be swindled, get swindled by someone who has been at it for a long time and has swindled lots of others.  It's less embarrassing.

Comment: I know this is somewhat of a frivolous answer, but I think well-written humour has a place in this site to complement the more serious answers which are often of necessity rather dry. It enriches our stackexchange culture. "It's only a game" after all. However the only reaction this received was a single downvote! That amazes me. And where is poor pokep now? Not here, that's for sure!

Comment: @Laska  Don't fret.  I'm still here.  And for me, only one downvote is like a +1.  I have two kids, so all my jokes at home are guaranteed at least two downvotes.  Three if the wife is in the room.

Comment: Hurray glad you are still here more answers please (although I can’t promise to downvote you :-)